# Sporadic sound problem on debian 9

Tags: linux, debian, audio, pulseaudio

I have a problem with the sound on debian 9 and I don't know how to diagnose my problem.

My sound works sporadically, when I turn on the computer I never know if my sound driver will work. If I reset the computer enough times it will eventually work. I have installed pulse audio volume control and I see the following devices under Configuration/Built-in audio:

```
Analog Stereo Duplex
Analog Stereo Output
Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (unplugged)
Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (unplugged)
Digital Stereo 7.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (unplugged)
Digital Stereo 5.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (unplugged)
Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (unplugged)
Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (unplugged)
Analog Stereo Input (unplugged)
Off
```

I have selected Analog Stereo Output and I'm able to hear the sound.
When the sound doesn't work I see the following list:

```
Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (unplugged)
Digital Stereo 7.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (unplugged)
Digital Stereo 5.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (unplugged)
Off
```

I have no idea how sound works under Linux and how to diagnose the problem. I have the impression I might have concurrent services trying to get hold of the resource that might be why it works sometimes but I don't know how to verify my claim.

Any ideas?

Thanks